# How to get rid of degree sign?

Tags: python, string

Here is my code:

```
temperature = forecast.find(class_ = "myforecast-current-lrg").get_text()
temperature.replace("u'\N{DEGREE SIGN}'", '')
```

However this has not worked, and I was wondering what approach to use to remove a degree sign from my string.

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What is `forecast`? Also, the question has nothing to do with the "degree sign".

Comment: @randomir Temperature is a string containing "72(degree sign) F". I was trying to get rid of the degree sign, but was unsure of what to put into the replace statement to get rid of the degree sign. the forecast variable is not necessary

Comment: Ok, than the first line is just noise. It would be much clearer to say `temperature = "72(degree sign) F"` instead.

Comment: Ok, sorry however I wasn't sure if possibly the first line might play a role in terms of how the temperature variable is initially made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the extra double quotes and reassign it to your variable:

```
temperature = temperature.replace(u'\N{DEGREE SIGN}', '')
```

Comment: Thank you, this did it for me. I forgot that strings were immutable was definitely my biggest issue

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
temperature = temperature.replace(u'\N{DEGREE SIGN}', '')
```

(strings are immutable, so `.replace` does not change the string, it creates a new string)

Comment: As grovina said, the double quotes around the outside also have to be removed, however yeah the immutable part is the main thing I forgot about

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Double quotes must be removed also.

Comment: Right, I have copy-pasted from OP's question without noticing that.